# Alexa ask-cli how to add a custom https server

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I'm not able deploy alexa skill using alexa-cli tool (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ask-cli) when I try to deploy my skill with a https server

As an error I get:

```
  ◞  Creating new skill...Call create-skill error.
Error code: 400
{
  "message": "Skill manifest is not valid.",
  "violations": [
    {
      "message": "No default regionalized endpoint is defined."
    }
  ]
}
```

Im using an example skill.json from:
https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-hello-world/blob/master/skill.json

A problem is how to add custom uri endpoint. I dont want to host my skill in AWS lambda function.

I tried to follow documentation:
https://developer.amazon.com/de/docs/smapi/ask-cli-command-reference.html
but I dont know what Im doing wrong...

Could sombody please take a look at my json and alexa-cli documentation? Why Im getting a such weird message?

```
"No default regionalized endpoint is defined."
```

?

```
{
    "manifest": {
        "publishingInformation": {
            "locales": {
                "en-US": {
                    "summary": "Sample Short Description",
                    "examplePhrases": [
                        "Alexa open hello world",
                        "Alexa tell hello world my name is bill",
                        "Alexa tell hello world I want to play"
                    ],
                    "name": "trivia",
                    "description": "Sample Full Description"
                }
            },
            "isAvailableWorldwide": true,
            "testingInstructions": "Sample Testing Instructions.",
            "category": "KNOWLEDGE_AND_TRIVIA",
            "distributionCountries": []
        },
        "apis": {
            "custom": {
                "endpoint": {
                    "sourceDir": "./lambda/custom",
                    "uri": "https://customapi.sampleskill.com",
                    "  sslCertificateType": "Wildcard"
                },
                "regions": {
                    "EU": {
                        "endpoint": {
                            "uri": "https://customapi.sampleskill.com",
                            "sslCertificateType": "Trusted"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "manifestVersion": "1.0"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok for those who faced that problem in the future ;) Important is that in your skill root directory you have that file:

```
.ask/config
```

It should look like:

```
{
  "deploy_settings": {
    "default": {
      "skill_id": "put here your skill id or leave it blank",
      "was_cloned": false,
      "merge": {
        "manifest": {
          "apis": {
            "custom": {
              "endpoint": {
                "uri": "https://yourhttps.de",
                "sslCertificateType": "Wildcard"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

after that you can use ask-cli with the https server as an endpoint :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    "apis": {
        "custom": {
            "endpoint": {
                "uri": "https://customapi.sampleskill.com",
                "sslCertificateType": "Wildcard"
            },
            "regions": {
                "EU": {
                    "endpoint": {
                        "uri": "https://customapi.sampleskill.com",
                        "sslCertificateType": "Trusted"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In the default config you had set `sourceDir` which doesn't make much sense for endpoints outside AWS Lambda. Second your config contained whitespace around `sslCertificateType`, which also might cause the problem.

Comment: I have already tried with this solution ;( Im getting that when I put your code into json: [Error]: Invalid url info.
Cannot find valid lambda function with the given name, nor find sourceDir as codebase path to create lambda function.

Comment: Could you please provide the contents of your ./.ask/config ?

Comment: @AnnaK you have sourceDir as a property of your custom endpoint. That tells the CLI that it should deploy the skill code as a Lambda function. Please remove the sourceDir and retry

Comment: Nope, ask-cli returns in that case: [Error]: Invalid url info.
Cannot find valid lambda function with the given name, nor find sourceDir as codebase path to create lambda function.